# Path before slash in Docker run/build? And why is there a dot?

Tags: docker

I'm following the getting started page. I have a few questions that I don't understand

```
docker build -t giantswarm/sparkexample .
```

I don't follow the "giantswarm" path and the `.` after `giantswarm/sparkexample`

```
docker run -d -p 4567:4567 giantswarm/sparkexample
```

Same question about docker run "giantswarm"

Comment: These are all answered in a Docker tutorial somewhere

Comment: please make a specific question. Read the stack overflow docs. What did you not understand exactly? the dot at the end of the command? the "-p"?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've been reading thru the docs. I never post on Stack Overflow without searching.  Actually I don't understand the path "giantswarm/sparkexample", what is giantswarm, and why the"." and in the maven project there is other files:  swarm.json

Comment: This specific question does not really pertain to Java, Maven, or Spark. Only Docker

Answer (score 1):

You are building an image from the current directory (a dot), the "path"  before the slash is going to be part of the image tag name (tag by `-t`), and it's only a naming convention, not a path

(Technically, it is a path, but only to DockerHub)

You have to build or pull a container image before you run it and use need to use the same name to do so

Comment: is the giantswarm the container image?

Comment: The whole thing is the name of the image `giantswarm/sparkexample`

Comment: You can also  pull from Docker Hub https://hub.docker.com/r/giantswarm/sparkexample/

Comment: but my target in the docker file is target/sparkexample-jar-with-dependencies.jar. So I'm putting my jar file in the container with the JVM to run?

Comment: That trailing period sends all files into the Docker build process. Whatever happens to your JAR file depends on the content of the Dockerfile

Comment: I don't have a path in my maven project that includes giantswarm? so why do I need add it to the build docker.  why I added Java, spark, and docker as labels? this question is all related!  Thank you again for the help

Comment: I don't know what this "giantswarm" thing is other than a name... Your Java project does not need to know anything about the Docker environment. It's the container that bundles whatever you tell it to

Answer (score 0):

When you call 
    docker build -t giantswarm/sparkexample .

-t is a  tag name for the container and you can call it anything! In this case the tag name is "giantswarm/sparkexample". The "/" is not a directory path! From the same directory where your docker file is you call:

```
docker build -t <anything you want name>  .
```

The ".' says include everything in this directory in the container.